# When $e$ is an eigenvector to $G$ prove that $e$ is an eigenvector of $G+k I$ and $G^2$

Tags: matrices

I've just started learning matrices and I've been shown how to perform row operations, how to find an inverse matrix, how to find eigenvectors from a given matrix, reduced-echelon form, basis, dim(M), rank(M), etc. However, I've just come across this question:

> The vector **e** is an eigenvector of the square matrix **G**. Show that:
>   $i.$ **e** is an eigenvector of **G** + *k***I**, where *k* is a scalar and **I** is an identity matrix.
>   $ii.$ **e** is an eigenvector of **G$^2$**

I know that applying the general rule $Ax = \lambda x \implies (A-\lambda I)x = 0$ will somehow help me here. But without being given any matrix to work with I'm not sure what sort of result I'm meant to achieve, or how I'm supposed to "prove" the two statements.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definition of Eigenvectors, let's say $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, so that $Ge=\lambda e$
$$(G+k I) \cdot e= G e + k I e = \lambda e + k e = (\lambda +k ) e$$
for the second 
$$G^2 e = G G e = G (G e) = G \lambda e= \lambda G e = \lambda^2 e$$

Comment: Is that first line the definition of eigenvectors? Please explain. It's slightly different from the equation I know of, so I'm not sure where it comes from.

Comment: A vector $x\neq 0$ is called an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ if $A x = \lambda x$

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why $(G+kI)\cdot e = \lambda e + ke$. All I have so far is that $Ax = \lambda Ix \implies A=\lambda I$; $x$ is an eigenvector. Could you shed some more light on that please?

Comment: you can't devide by $x$ they are vectors, you have the equation $(A-\lambda I)x= Ax-\lambda x =0\implies Ax=\lambda x$ and i just multiply it out

Comment: Right, but I still don't understand the connection between $Gx = kx$ and $(G+kI)\cdot x = \lambda x + kx$ :S

Comment: Take $e=x$ ?! multiply it out, use that the identity is the identity sry i really don't know where the proble mis, maybe its better to come in the chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7903/discussion-between-ozzy-and-dominic-michaelis)